# Custom SVG symbol using HighCharts in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, highcharts

I would like to add a custom SVG as a marker for my HighCharts scatterplot, but the SVGRenderer method does not seem to work well with TypeScript. Has anyone had any luck creating custom SVGs in TS?

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom SVG marker in scatter series type you have to add it as a module. So save it as a Javascript file and edit it by adding below code to the beginning and end of a file (cross marker example from this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/):

```
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
    factory(Highcharts);
  }
})(function(Highcharts) {
  // Define a custom symbol path
  Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function(x, y, w, h) {
    return ["M", x, y, "L", x + w, y + h, "M", x + w, y, "L", x, y + h, "z"];
  };
  if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross =
      Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
  }
});
```

Next, load it to the chart component:

```
require('./relative-path-to-the-module-file/module-file-name')(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/4wx4n70q3x

**Docs:**

- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper